# New NSString substringWithRange: Error Message

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, osx-snow-leopard

I'm getting an interesting new error with iOS 4:

```
-[NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Invalid range {11, 4294967295}; this will become an exception for apps linked on SnowLeopard. Warning shown once per app execution.
```

The error is caused by a snippet of code I got from a blog post that helps Title Case a string, and it's not going to be hard to fix, but I haven't seen this mentioned anywhere else, and I'm assuming Apple wants people to stop using the magic 4294967295 number.

Does anyone know about the history / background of this change?

EDIT: Source for the Title Case code is located at: http://vengefulcow.com/titlecase/ It's the objective-c port (obviously). Line 116 is the offender. Clearly it's a problem only under some specific condition. I'm still tracking it down.

Comment: Well, 4294967295 is a magic number. Its the highest number you can get with 32 bits, and since Snow Leopards 64 it's not. their probably taking note of that since iPhone is 32 bit.

Comment: You're range is to big, you are probably going past 4294967295 and then it is giving you an exception that you can't do that on iPhone.

Comment: Meh.  Post the code.  I don't want to go grubbing through some random example .zip.

Comment: You do realize this wasn't meant for iPhone right?

Comment: @thyrgle; not sure I know what you mean... it's unmanaged objective-c, and on the homepage the guy says specifically " it might be useful in an iPhone app". In what way is it _not_ meant for the iPhone?

Comment: O wait... sorry... man I have been having a bad past week of advice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsigned 4294967295 is the same as the signed uint32_t value for -1.   I've seen problems where a 32 bit app archived -1 and a 64 bit app unarchived it as a Big Ass Length (terribly fun when it was Xcode calling `malloc(4294967295)` during the 64-bit bring-up).

The Cocoa frameworks are detecting that you passed in a range where the length is longer than the string itself.  Warning now, with truncated results, but it'll be a hard error in the future.

(In some cases, NSNotFound can cause these kinds of issues).

Comment: Yes, this was the problem, and also explains the motivation for the change on Apple's part. Thank you.